# RStudio: how to find and extract max value?

Tags: rstudio

Say I have the dataframe df.df and I want to find the highest value.

```
Molly 290
Susan 189
Zoe 276
...
```

if I use

```
max(df.df)
```

it'll give me

```
[1] Zoe
```

But I want to extract "290". What command would I use to do so?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- read.table( text = "Molly 290
Susan 189
Zoe 276")
max(df[2]) #Column 2
```

Comment: Code only answers can generally be improved by adding some explanation to go along with the code. In this case maybe you want to explain that the `[2]` is addressing the second piece of data?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.